# Document Viewer, File Opener not working in ionic

Tags: file, ionic-framework, ionic4, file-transfer, fileopener2

I am new to ionic. I want to open pdf file which is in server.

For that the following `plugins`. But still pdf is not opening.

**First I have installed and added these plugins.**

```
 1. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file  
    npm install @ionic-native/file
 2. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-opener2  
    npm install @ionic-native/file-opener
 3. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer  
    npm install @ionic-native/file-transfer
 4. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-document-viewer  
    npm install @ionic-native/document-viewer
```

**In my `app.module.ts`**

```
import { DocumentViewer } from '@ionic-native/document-viewer/ngx';  
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';  
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';  
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';  
  
@NgModule({  
   declarations: [AppComponent],  
   entryComponents: [],  
   providers: [  
    DocumentViewer,
    File,
    FileOpener,
    FileTransfer,  
   ],  
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]  
})
```

**In my `home.page.ts`**

```
constructor(document: DocumentViewer, public file: File, public ft: FileTransfer, public fileOpener: FileOpener) { }
viewBook() {
   let path = this.file.dataDirectory;  
   const transfer = this.ft.create();  
   transfer.download("https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf", path + 'myfile.pdf').then(entry => {  
   let url = entry.toURL();  
   this.document.viewDocument(url, 'application/pdf', {});
}
```

This is not works.

I also tried this.
**In `home.page.ts`**

```
this.fileOpener.open(url, 'application/pdf');
```

But this also not works.

Please tell me what's wrong here.
Thanks.

Comment: console.log() your url variable. `let url = entry.toURL(); console.log(url)` and see what inside it.

Comment: Okay, I will update here, that, what response I get `btry.ToRL`

Answer (score 0):

Add plugins on Config.xml file than try